# How can I do performance and load testing for login authenticated web application?

Tags: manual-testing

Please someone help me. How can I do performance and load testing for login authenticated web application.?

Answer (score 2):

There are many tools available to do performance /load testing ex:Jmeter,Blazemeter..etc

If you are doing jmeter it can be achieved in more than one way like by creating HTTP request or recording the flow.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Jmeter`. `Jmeter` is best for load and performance testing. you can create `HTTP` request. `Jmeter`  also display the response timing of all `HTTP` request with status.